# mikrotik расширить сеть на две под-сети

Tags: сеть, mikrotik, маршрут

*Старый вопрос*

*Если я это сделаю в IP / Addresses :*

```
Address : 192.168.0.1/24 на 192.168.0.1/23
Network : 192.168.0.0
Interface : bridge2
```

*Упадёт сеть или нет? Цель расширения для принятия адресов с клиентов на адресах `192.168.0.x/24` и `192.168.1.x/24`. DHCP сервер выдаёт адреса `192.168.0.x/24` , а зарезервированные статические будут в `192.168.1.x/24`.*

Я передумал расширять маску. Сделал два бриджа с адресами 192.168.0.1 (eth2 eth3) и 192.168.1.1 (eth4 eth5). Как сделать маршрут между двумя под сетями, чтобы из 192.168.0.x/24 можно было пинговать 192.168.1.y/24 ?

Нашёл только маскарадом

```
/ip firewall nat
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat src-address=192.168.0.0/24 dst-address=192.168.1.0/24
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat src-address=192.168.1.0/24 dst-address=192.168.0.0/24
```

А можно обратный адрес из другой сети сделать? Не маскарад?

Comment: Раз уж планируются работы с риском отвала сети, то надо запланировать отвал сети. Я бы в таком случае даже бы перешёл на более ёмкую сеть, например `10.0.0.0/16`

Comment: Я сомневаюсь просто, что будет нестыковка с броадкастами. Клиент хочет адрес  `0.x` а ему пришлют два DHCP сервера `0.y` и `1.z` ?? @Sheridan

Comment: Просто запланируйте отвал сети. Предупредите, согласуйте время, напишите инструкции для пользователей (если нет возможности самому бегать по ним). Что нибудь пойдёт не так обязательно.

Comment: Одна сеть `10.0.0.0/16` не прокатит, мне нужно две разные сети. @Sheridan

Comment: две независимые организации? две разделённые сети? может стоит их разграничить пограничным шлюзом и сделать две полноценных сети со своими dhcpd/named/etc? А на пограничном шлюзе отрезать огнестеной лишнее

Comment: Придётся переписать руками статические резервированные адреса, если они настроены на клиенте, и установить правильную маску. Ещё лучше - перевести их на резервирование по МАС. Отвал сети - планируйте, ибо после смены настроек узлы некоторое время, до перезапроса, будут использовать старые параметры. Для снижения проблемного времени перенастройте DHCP на малое время выделения (ориентировочно по минуте на каждые 10-15 узлов) и дождитесь, пока все клиенты не получат это время жизни. Хотя я бы уходил в 172.16... так можно обойтись без простоя.

Comment: Можно сделать шлюз в mikrotik IP / Routes. Только доступный. Ни разу не делал. @Sheridan

Comment: Ну, кмк, "как сделать из микротика пограничный шлюз?" - достойно отдельного вопроса.

Comment: У меня осталось два варианта. Или два роутера соединённых друг с другом через IP / Routes (дорого). Или один роутер с макой /23. И клиенты с масками /24. Какие настройки (подводные камни) нужно подправить для этого?  @Sheridan

Comment: я до сих пор не понимаю зачем две сети. Сделайте одну, большую, сразу /16. Резервируйте адреса по MAC. Выделите "гостевой" диаппазон...

Comment: *один роутер с макой /23. И клиенты с масками /24. Какие настройки (подводные камни) нужно подправить для этого?* Это будет один большой кирпич, а не мелкие подводные камешки. Не делайте так. *Можно сделать шлюз в mikrotik IP / Routes.* Маршрутизация между подсетями, где одна входит в другую? флаг в руки. Хотя... вдруг и вправду это возможно?

Comment: Маршрутизация написана здесь : https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Simple_Static_Routing Просто не хочется два роутера. @Akina

Comment: Что-то то ли я ослеп, то ли показанные там подсети ни разу не пересекаются... вы уж тыкните пальцем, а?

Comment: ``один роутер с макой /23. И клиенты с масками /24. Какие настройки (подводные камни) нужно подправить для этого? Это будет один большой кирпич, а не мелкие подводные камешки. Не делайте так. Можно сделать шлюз в mikrotik IP / Routes.`` Бесклассовая маршрутизация с сделана для того, что бы снижать нагрузку на маршрутизаторах: маршрутизатор обслуживающий 15 сетей находящихся подряд в одном диапазоне может у себя на борту объединить их одной укрупненной маской, при этом действительно во вкладке "/ip dhcp-server network" выдавать разные настройки для разных сетей.

Comment: НО! Важно учитывать, что все может пойти не так. По этому перед началом настроек действительно нужно занизить время аренды адресов до минимального, потом перевести маршрутизатор в save mode и только после этого приступать к настройке!

Answer (score 0):

Пример использования вкладки с описаниями разных сетей и даже частей от целых диапазонов, которые можно использовать для решения данной задачи. А на вкладке `/ip dhcp-server lease` просто привязывать mac адрес клиента нужному адресу. После чего DHCP сервер RouterOS вышлет ему нужные значения маски, шлюза и так далее которые найдет для этого адреса в таблице network

```
ip dhcp-server network
add address=192.168.21.0/24 dns-server=192.168.21.1,1.1.1.1 gateway=192.168.21.1
add address=192.168.21.2/32 dns-server=192.168.21.129,8.8.8.8 gateway=192.168.21.129 netmask=24
add address=192.168.21.3/32 dns-server=192.168.21.65,8.8.8.8 gateway=192.168.21.65 netmask=24
```

P.S.: Обратите внимание, что даже шлюз по умолчанию можно выдавать другой!

Comment: Непонятен ваш ответ. Вы пример предлагаете для сети /24. А у меня их две штуки по /24. DHCP обслуживания в роутере нет. Сервер внутри этим занимается. Я сейчас остановился на IP forwarding этих сетей. ( Что-то типа чтобы пинг из 192.168.0.x/24 находил клиента 192.168.1.y/24 )

Comment: Да, я предпологал что dhcp на маршрутизаторе находится. А с форвардингом решение по идее рабочее, но в будущем не обслуживаемое. Ну то есть такие вещи в конфигурации плохо читаются (если на пример нужно будет поправить, а автор этой конфигурации в отпуске, а заменяющий человек может не разобраться)